# Changing colour of ImageHistogram

Tags: color, histograms

Is there a way I can show the three `ImageHistogram[]`'s in different colours?

`Show[ ImageHistogram[edit[[1]], Appearance -> "Separated"], ImageHistogram[edit[[2]], Appearance -> "Separated"], ImageHistogram[edit[[3]], Appearance -> "Separated"],  ]`

[image]

Comment: In theory, you should be able to use something like `PlotStyle -> Array[ColorData[61], 3]`, but it does not seem to work here...

Comment: @J.M. ChartStyle doesn't seem to work either

Comment: Someone else would need to confirm, but I think this is worth reporting to Support.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ColorReplace` to replace `{Red, Green, Blue}` with desired colors:

```
ClearAll[colReplace]
colReplace = ColorReplace[ImageHistogram[#, Appearance -> "Separated", ImageSize -> Large], 
    Thread[{Red, Green, Blue} -> #2]] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
edit1 = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUr0a.png"]
```

[image]

```
edit2 = ImageAdjust[edit, .1];

edit3 = ColorBalance[edit, .1];

Row[{edit1, edit2, edit3}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

```
colReplace[edit1, ColorData[97] /@ {1, 2, 3}]
```

[image]

```
Show[MapThread[colReplace, 
  {{edit1, edit2, edit3}, Partition[ColorData[97] /@ Range[9], 3]}]]
```

[image]

You can also use `ReplaceAll` to get the same results:

```
ClearAll[replaceColors]
replaceColors = ReplaceAll[Thread[{Red, Green, Blue} -> #2]]@
    ImageHistogram[#, Appearance -> "Separated", ImageSize -> Large] &;
```

Answer (score 3):

The second suggestion by @kglr seems like a natural approach (which ensures the result still has Head `Graphics` and not `Image`).

Another solution would be to manually make a `Histogram` for each channel:

```
GraphicsColumn[
MapThread[Histogram[Flatten[ImageData[#1]],ChartStyle->#2]&,{ColorSeparate[edit1,"RGB"],Array[ColorData[61],3]}]
]
```

However, this also serves as more of an extended comment to highlight a curious behaviour (as hinted by the comments above).
Note that `ImageHistogram` clearly has special logic for handling `RGB` images. This can be seen by comparing a 4-channel image `ColorSpace`, e.g. `CMYK`:

```
With[{cmyk = ColorCombine[ColorSeparate[edit1, "CMYK"], "CMYK"]},
 ImageHistogram[cmyk, Appearance -> "Separated"]]
```

[image]

Curiously, adding `PlotStyle -> Array[ColorData[57], 4]` also fails on this example, returning all histograms with the last specified color.
Perhaps this is indeed worth reporting to WR Support.